# XPath to get node name based on existence of child node

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following nodes:

```
<resource>
    <DataField1>
         <label>...</label>
         <alert>...</alert>
     </DataField1>
     <DataField2>
         <label>...</label>
     </DataField2>
     <DataField3>
        <label>...</label>
        <alert>...</alert>
     </DataField3>
</resource>
```

and would like to show the name of the 1st and 3rd node because it exists the child node "alert".

```
DataField1
DataField3
```

With the following XPath I can show the nodes:

```
 //resource/*[alert]
```

Result:

```
<DataField1>
    <label>...</label>
    <alert>...</alert>
</DataField1>
<DataField3>
    <label>...</label>
    <alert>...</alert>
</DataField3>
```

but this is not what I want.

Comment: What do you mean by "name"? The label? Or DataField1/3?

Comment: @Markus, i mean the label of the second node

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `label`:

```
//resource/*[alert]/label
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I was looking for. I need the name/label of the second level nodes. It is described in detail

Comment: The XPath expression selects `resource/DataField1/label` and `resource/DataField3/label`. If this is not what you are looking for, please specify in more detail what your result should look like.

Comment: When I use local-name(//resource/*[alert]) it shows DataField1. But I want DataField1 and DataField3.

Comment: That's because `local-name()` selects the first node from a given node set.

Answer (score 0):

> `/resource/*/alert/parent::*`

returns

```
Element='<DataField1>
     <label>...</label>
     <alert>...</alert>
 </DataField1>'
Element='<DataField3>
    <label>...</label>
    <alert>...</alert>
 </DataField3>'
```

Comment: OP has already shown the same output and the user do not want such output.